# Recursive floodFill function? C++

Tags: c++, function, recursion, flood-fill

So recursion is not my strong point, and I have been challenged to make a recursive floodFill function that fills a vector of a vector of ints with 1's if the value is zero. My code keeps segfaulting for reasons beyond me. Perhaps my code will make that sound more clear.

**This is the grid to be flood filled:**

```
vector<vector<int> > grid_;
```

It belongs to an object I created called "Grid" that is basically a set of functions to help manipulate the vectors. The grid's values are initialized to all zeros.

**This is my flood fill function:**

```
void floodFill(int x, int y, Grid & G)
{

if (G.getValue(x,y))
{
    G.setValue(x,y,1);
    if(x < G.getColumns()-1 && x >= 0 && y < G.getRows()-1 && y >= 0)
    floodFill(x+1,y,G);

    if(x < G.getColumns()-1 && x >= 0 && y < G.getRows()-1 && y >= 0)
    floodFill(x,y+1,G);

    if(x < G.getColumns()-1 && x >= 0 && y < G.getRows()-1 && y >= 0)
    floodFill(x-1,y,G);

    if(x < G.getColumns()-1 && x >= 0 && y < G.getRows()-1 && y >= 0)
    floodFill(x,y-1,G);

}       
}
```

The intention here is to have the function check if a point's value is zero, and if it is, change it to one. Then it should check the one above it for the same. It does this until it either finds a 1 or hits the end of the vector. Then it tries another direction and keeps going until the same conditions as above and so on and so forth until its flood filled.

Can anyone help me fix this? Maybe tell me whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Aside from what lezebulon says below, the if condition looks like it should be `if (!G.getValue(x,y))`, assuming `getValue` is returning what it sounds like it is.

Comment: Yup, I'm pretty sure you'd get an infinite loop since you keep writing 1 all over the same cases

Comment: lezebulon, you're absolutely right, I got it working now, however its only written one 1. I hope its not asking too much, but being new to recursion, how can I modify the algorithm to actually crawl across my vector and fill it all up?

Comment: it is already crawling through the indexes so I think that G.setValue(x,y,1); must not work as expected

Comment: Does your code segfault or does it stack overflow? A naive recursive floodfill algorithm can very quickly eat up even a large stack, depending on the size of the vector space.

Comment: This code will almost always result in a stack overflow even after the fix in the accepted answer.  I posted why below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(x < G.getColumns()-1 && x >= 0 && y < G.getRows()-1 && y >= 0)
    floodFill(x-1,y,G);
```

won't work, since you can access index -1 of the underlying vector if `x == 0`

Same goes for `floodFill(x,y-1,G);`

Answer (score 1):

This code has a lot of problems.  First of all you check with `if(G.getValue(x,y))` whether the value at a position is 1, and if so, then you set it to 1 with `G.setValue(x,y,1)`.  Think about this for a second, this can't be right.  When will you ever set non-zero values to 1?

Then, another more subtle point is that you shouldn't do the recursion into neighbors if they are already set to 1.

As it stands the code you have will likely run until you overflow the stack because just going to recurse forever on the 1's that are connected to wherever you start from.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
void floodFill(int x, int y, Grid &g) {
  if(x >= g.getColumns() || y >= g.getRows()) {
    return;
  }

  floodFill(x+1, y, g);

  if( x == 0 ) {
    floodFill(x, y+1, g);
  }

  g.setValue(x, y, 1)
}
```

I think that will fill the grid without every hitting the same coordinate multiple times, and whenever either index is out of bounds it just returns so no chance of a seg fault.

Comment: This has to be started from 0,0 though

Comment: That's true. I wasn't sure from the OP's comment whether he was describing the intention of the code he wrote or the functional requirements. I guess I assumed the former, incorrectly.